# Adobe Illustrators wrongly exports image (differs from preview when exporting)

Tags: adobe-illustrator

everybody!

So I am trying to get a nice picture of my face in a circle with transparent background for the CV and this is the preview image:

[image: Note that THERE IS SPACE between the circle and the border]

But when I export, this is what I get: Take a look at the right corner.
[image: Take a look at the border on the right.]

This is the export window:
[image: This is the export window]

Comment: Have you checked your artboard dimensions and clipping masks? Looks like the artboard isn't big enough to export the whole image.

Comment: What are your settings for export? Example: Are you using the artboard or the image?

Comment: I can't recreate the problem. Sorry.  How did you export it?  What format? What settings? Is the transparency part of the image?  Have you tried using a photo with a circle as a clipping mask?

Comment: Doesn't matter much what's in the export window, in your case the problem will be in your layers / artboards /objects. We need to see a screenshot of that.

Answer (score -1):

**Photoshop?**

For you purposes, wouldn't the task be better accomplished in Photoshop?
As far as the blurry export, you need to access your export settings. I'm assuming you have a small image being exported at 72dpi.

Comment: I is being exported as PNG 24.

It is not a problem of the canvas since the first image is a preview already.

Comment: What are the pixel dimensions of the exported image?

Comment: I dont know where to check that, so I uploaded another picture.